# Keep Helper Column Functions on Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a combined query from Power Query that I put into a table on a spreadsheet.  On that same spreadsheet I add helper columns with a function.

The problem is when there is no data for the query, the helper functions are deleted (since the entire row is deleted) and not added with new data.  Is there a way to get the functions to repopulate?

Comment: Add the formula in the query itself as a Custom Column. You will need to define it using the M language.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that in M.  So let's say I have a column with a sales ID, and then a sales person.  It is possible to have multiple sales people on one sales ID.  So I had a helper column that combined SalesPerson&SalesID so that I could get a unique count per sales person.

I am not sure how to do that with M.  Right now I use COUNTIF formulas

Comment: You can create a new column in Power Query to combine SalesPerson&SalesID. The count is the analysis that is done in Excel, not in Power Query. You don't really need the unique count per sales person in each row of your query table. Build a pivot table for that.

Comment: Sadly I can't use a pivot table, or at least I haven't figured out how to make one work.  I still need to show all the potential sales people, even ones with zero data.

I am using COUNTIF to do a 1/COUNTIF for each entry, as I am accounting for "duplicates" with multiple people per sales job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the query properties? Select "Preserve column..." and "insert entire rows...".

[image]

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it either clears or deletes the unused cells, including the ones with my functions.

Comment: How about putting the query in sheet1, and then duplicate the data in sheet2 with the helper columns. If you have some max number of possible rows (say 1000), you could extend the helper formulae to row 1000 right from the start. A1 in sheet2 could be something like =IF(ISBLANK(sheet1!A1),"",sheet1!A1)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing