# How do you create a table in Excel with a combination of external data and Excel formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a query in Excel that pulls about five columns of data and thousands of rows from an Oracle database. I want to add additional columns to the right of this data, in the same table, that have various formulas to process the columns from the database. But this results in two things:

1. Table refreshes from the database take several minutes instead of seconds.
2. The additional columns get full of #REF errors.

I think what's happening with #2 is that the refresh is deleting the cells with data and then creating new cells with the refreshed data. I seem to recall an option somewhere in Excel of what to do in this case but I don't remember where it was.

As for #1, no idea. I'm using Excel 365 with an OLEDB connection to Oracle.

Surely this is all something basic I'm overlooking...thanks for help.

Comment: might be worth sharing the formulas, hard to fix when you can't seem them :)

Comment: Rather than adding columns to the spreadsheet to the right of the data after it's refreshed, you should edit the query that is pulling the data from Oracle and add your calculated columns as part of the query itself.

Comment: The option you're looking for is in Data>Queries & Connections>Properties

Comment: yes, use the data connection stuff (formally known as power query) to further massage your data before final presentation in excel.

Comment: You need to use SQL for the Query should create new column using Aggregate function like this one,,,,  `Select Age,if(Age > 18,'Ok','No') AS Result from
TableName;` ,, use the required action!!

Comment: I'd love to edit the query to do all the processing in the DB, but it's not feasible. The data to be processed is a mishmash of data in the DB and data that lives only in spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue: Formulas not filling down next to data connection refresh**

Not sure if its the same for OLEDB but if you pull data from a CSV / text file, there are options in the connection properties where you can tell Excel to fill down formulas adjacent to the csv data, and what excel should do with in case the new data has more or less data rows than before. In theory, with the correct setting, the formulas should be refreshed as well. See my answer here for a similar problem:

```
https://superuser.com/a/1633714/1241807
```

Also see the comments. If for some reason those options are not available with OLEDB connections, you could opt for "cloning" the sheet to a new sheet with references as described in those comments. Trouble is... those references will probably also break #REF style.

To circumvent this, you could use indirect text references in your formulae, ie. instead of:

```
=IF(A1 = 1, B1, C1)
```

use:

```
=IF(indirect("A1") = 1, indirect("B1"), indirect("C1"))
```

Except, this is a very bad idea for large spreadsheets, as indirect() is a volatile function - meaning it will recalculate with each and every small change in the workbook (and even other open workbooks). Volatility could also be the reason why your workbook is already so slow. Do you perhaps use OFFSET, RAND, NOW, TODAY, INDIRECT or conditional formatting in your workbook (to name a few)? These are all volatile and can be a huge speed bump. Perhaps also checkout my answer on improving workbook speed here:

https://superuser.com/a/1643467/1241807

**Alternative solution 1: Manual formulae saving to prevent #REF errors**

Before a refresh, hit Formulas ribbon > Show Formulas or CTRL+` to switch to formula view. Select all your formulae and copy (CTRL+C) and paste into Notepad or Word (CTRL+V). Clear your formulae cells in Excel. Now refresh your data connection. After which, proceed to copy and paste your formula back into Excel from Notepad / Word.

**Alternative solution 2: Non-volatile indirect or offset in Excel**

You can, in certain situations make use of the non-volatile index function and/or *relative named ranges* instead of the volatile indirect or offset functions. To make absolute references use for e.g. $B$3

```
=INDEX($A$1:$Z$1000, 3 , 2)      ...make the range only as big as necessary as this will also impact speed
```

and for relative references, say reference to B3 from D3

```
=INDEX($A$1:$Z$1000, ROW() , COLUMN()-2)
```

In some use cases $A$1:$Z$1000 may still result in #REF errors upon data refresh or specific data inserts or deletes. For those you have the option of relative named ranges. If you place your cursor in E2 and then define a name called "FourLeft" with *refers to* as `=A2`, (**NOT $A$2**), you can use FourLeft in any cell and it will always return the cell value four columns to the left. In that way, the above formula can be written e.g. like this (defining two more names):

```
=IF(FourLeft = 1, ThreeLeft, TwoLeft)
```

Be careful with both approaches, as behaviour differs from normal references, especially when copying and pasting, inserting or deleting data.